# How to select a specific character in string by index in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have some string, lets say:

```
"YGQST"
```

How can I loop in this string using C++ as the following pseudo code does:

```
string A = "YGQST";
for(int i=0; i <A.length; i++)
{
    if(A[i] != Q)
    {
       cout << "A != Q";  
    }
}
```

p.s.

In C# it's easy to do as you can measure the length of the string, but how to do it in C++?

UPDATE:

Will the same solution work for C?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: you can iterate through a std::string as you did in c++.. string[i] works fine

Comment: *Will the same solution work for C?* There is no std::string in C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ we have std::string. There's really not much difference.

```
string A = "YGQST";
for(int i=0; i <A.length(); ++i)
{
    if(A[i] != 'Q')
    {
       cout << "A != Q\n";  
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is how to do it in C

```
const char *A = "YGQST";
for(; *A; ++A)
{
    if(*A != 'Q')
    {
       printf("A != Q\n");  
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan There is no `std::string` in `C`.

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan Not exactly, in C you'd use a raw c-string.

Comment: Thanks, the how will you do that in C (considering char[] instead of string)

Answer (score 3):

You can do exactly that. `string` has a [`length`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) method

```
string A = "YGQST";
for(int i=0; i < A.length(); ++i)
{
    if(A[i] != 'Q')
    {
       cout << "A != Q";  
    }
}
```

Or if you are using C++11, you can get the same effect by doing

```
string A = "YGQST";
for(auto const& letter : A)
{
    if(letter != 'Q')
    {
       cout << "A != Q";  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working on multiple compilers, so the second doesn't fit me. Will the same fit C code?